# How do I test the response of this service function in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following function in my service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { APP_CONST } from '../app-const';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getLandingData(): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get(this.landingApiEndPoint+this.api.landing_uri).pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          console.log('Res ', response);
          return response;
        })
   );
}
```

And for this function, I've written this test case:

```js
it('should get Landing Data', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const names = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}];
    service.getLandingData().subscribe((res)=>{
      expect(res).toEqual(names);
      console.log("Landing "+res);
      console.log("Landing names"+names);
      done();
    })
  });
```

But I keep getting this error: `Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)` 
I tried setting the default timeout interval, but no luck. I'm using **jasmine 4.2.0**. Please do let me know how I can test this correctly.

Comment: Use the [HttpClientTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpClientTestingModule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `HttpClientTestingModule` module in your tests.
And then you need either mock httpClient or use `HttpTestingController` to mock the requests.

For example:

```
describe('TestSuite', () => {
  let service: Service;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [Service]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(Service);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should get Landing Data', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const names = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }];

    service.updateAlias().subscribe((res)=>{
      expect(res).toEqual(names);
      console.log("Landing ", res);
      console.log("Landing names", names);
      done();
    });

    httpMock
      .expectOne('http://landing-page.com/url')
      .flush(names);
  });
});
```

Comment: My upvote is not visible, because of the low reputation. But be assured, I have upvoted your solution. The flush is what I was missing and it worked great!